# Why can't JavaScript append a node to hierarchy from code?

Tags: javascript, dom, hierarchy, appendchild

In a web app I'm writing, I get this error:

```
HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy
```

It happens when I `appendChild()` a node to another point in the DOM.

I'm having a hard time figuring this one out. Although I have a reproducible case, it doesn't make sense to me why it happens here. If I execute the exact same operation from within browser developer tools, it runs fine. However, when the code executes from a JavaScript file, it encounters the error.

Searching online has found other people with a similar issue but no resolution. What would you say?

Thank you! :)

**UPDATE**: Sorry for not including code before, the place where I was writing closed.

The exact line that causes an error is as follows. If I comment it out, the code runs fine:

```
document.getElementById(creature_name).appendChild(creature_array[nearestNeighbor]);

// creature_name is the ID of an SVG <g> element. creature_array[nearestNeighbor] is another SVG element, which should get moved to within the <g>.
```

I've moved the same child into the same part of the hierarchy manually. I've investigated with debugger and DOM inspector and been unable to find a cause of the problem.

Would more code help? It's an open source project so I can share as much as necessary. This is my first question here, so please excuse my newbie mistakes!

UPDATE 2: For anyone who comes across this later, it turns out that in my case I had prevented the node from trying to append itself, but had NOT prevented the node from trying to append its parent node as a child, which resulted in the error. (Trying to append a node to itself also fails.)

Comment: What are the two nodes and what is their relationship? Please provide a [mcve], otherwise we cannot really help you.

Comment: Where is the node? Where is the point in the DOM? A code example will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the reproducible case?  It's hard to make a guess without some code.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: We can't help you without your code, sorry.

Comment: Read the links people have given you about a minimal example. We cannot reproduce your issue from what you have posted.

Comment: You will get this error when you attempt to append a node to itself or one of its descendants. Why would you try to do that?

Comment: OK, sorry for supplying insufficient information, this is my first quesiton here. To answer your questions: The two nodes are SVG elements. Each one represents a game creature. They work fine as siblings. In this case one creature is consuming another creature, so the eaten gets appended within the eater. One possibility I've suspected is that I've made a mistake in the code to find the nearest neighbor, and thus that it's trying to append a node to itself. However, I've checked that and believe it to be conclusively ruled out by the code logic. I've updated the post with more info...

Comment: OK, I'm looking into that and will add more detail...

Comment: Would it help to post a live site example, or should it only be code? I can reproduce the error within the running game, but like I originally wrote it runs fine if I execute the code by hand, so I don't know how much script it would take to cause the issue in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that in my case I had prevented the node from trying to append itself, but had NOT prevented the node from trying to append its parent node as a child, which resulted in the error. (Trying to append a node to itself also fails.)